# Overriding the text color of a button

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design

Here is the code

```
export function ViewCurrentPitch(props){
    const actions = [
        <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={props.closeEditPitch}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        className= 'flat-button'
        label="Save"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onClick={props.savePitchBeingEdited}
      />,
    ];

    console.log(props)
    return (
        <Card key={props.pitch.id} className = 'form-margin card-width' zDepth={3}>
            <CardText>{props.pitch.subject} </CardText>
            <CardText className='card'>{props.pitch.pitch}</CardText>
            <CardActions className= 'this-is-a-test'>
                <FlatButton className= 'flat-button' label="Edit" onClick={(e) => {props.toggleEdit(e, props.pitch); console.log(props.state)}}/>
                    <Dialog
                        className="dialogBox"
                        title="Test"
                        actions={actions}
                        open={props.editPitch}
                        contentStyle={customContentStyle}
                        autoScrollBodyContent={true}
                    >
                        <TextFieldExampleCustomize currentValue = {props.pitchBeingEdited} updateNewPitch = {props.updatePitchBeingEdited} />
                    </Dialog>
                <FlatButton className= 'flat-button' label="Delete" onClick={(e) => {props.deletePitch(e, props.pitch)}} />
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

I am trying to make the button `<FlatButton ...>` a different color.

I tried adding the style in my `.css` file

```
.flat-button {
  color: #1A237E;
}
```

I tried on both the parent component as well as the specific component. Neither seem to work. Do I need to pass it as an inline style?

What am I doing wrong>

Comment: Color should only change the color of the text of the button, however if you are trying to change the color of the entire button background-color or background should fix your problem.

Comment: FlatButton should be a scoped style

Comment: hi @pirs i don't know what that means :-(

Comment: hi @MarshallMunoz I just want to change the text color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to : http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button

You can override the style with the attribute `style` like:

```
// Note: style is an object, not css
<FlatButton className='flat-button' style={color: 'pink'} />
```

Or put the `primary/secondary` color you are using in your template, like:

```
<FlatButton className='flat-button' primary=true />
```

FlatButton seems to be with a scoped css and shouldn't be modified by classic css, more : http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Comment: hmm. I added `style='{color:pink}'` to the inline `<FlatButton style='{color:pink}' label="Delete" onClick={(e) => {props.deletePitch(e, props.pitch)}} />` but it didn't do anything

Comment: ahh I got it `const buttonStyle = {color: 'pink'}` and then added `style={buttonStyle}`

Comment: in some hours you ll rock it for sure :-), read precisly the doc

Answer (score 0):

You should use the style property on the component when styling. For more this type of styling, and other techniques see here: https://survivejs.com/react/advanced-techniques/styling-react/

Comment: is there a way to set it in the CSS file so I don't have to do it for every button? or multiple style changes for every button?